# Converting string to datetime in yyyymmdd format

Tags: sql-server, string, datetime

I need to add days to a `varchar` representation in the `yyyymmdd` format.

I'm getting an error when converting a `varchar(8)` value to `datetime` in SQL Server 2005.

I don't have a clue why!

Here is what works:

```
select
   convert (datetime, '20111019')
from _table
```

This does not work, although the value in the column is `20111019`

```
select 
   convert (datetime, RechDatum)
from _table
```

I already tried:

```
convert (datetime, RechDatum, 112)
```

and

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
```

I was able to solve the problem with an own function. But I'm still confused and would be glad for answers of you!

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'getDateFromString' and type = 'FN')
DROP FUNCTION getDateFromString
GO
CREATE FUNCTION getDateFromString (@Cyear VARCHAR(4), @Cmonth smallint, @Cday smallint, @offsetdays smallint)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @day SMALLINT 
    DECLARE @month SMALLINT
    DECLARE @year SMALLINT
    SET @day = CAST (@Cday AS SMALLINT)
    SET @month = CAST (@Cmonth AS SMALLINT)
    SET @year = CAST (@Cyear AS SMALLINT)
    RETURN DateAdd(day, @offsetdays,
                (SELECT 
                    DateAdd (day, @day -1,
                        DateAdd (month, @month -1,
                            DateAdd (Year, @year-1900,0)))  ))
END
```

GO

Here is the table definition, it's part of an german ERP system:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuftrKopf](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IsSammelRechnung] [bit] NULL,
    [AuftragsNr] [int] NULL,
    [Kd_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Fahrer_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Debitor] [int] NULL,
    [Fz_ID] [int] NULL,
    [FHFz_ID] [int] NULL,
    [AuftrArt_ID] [int] NULL,
    [AuftrHerkunft_ID] [int] NULL,
    [AuftrZustand_ID] [int] NULL,
    [RechnungsArt_ID] [int] NULL,
    [AuftragVom] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [FertigAmUm] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [BringenAmUm] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [AbgeschlossenAmUm] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [StempelkartenNr] [int] NULL,
    [HuetchenNr] [int] NULL,
    [LeistungsDatum] [varchar](8) NULL,
[RechnDatum] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [ValutaDatum] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [NettoSummenspalte1] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NettoSummenspalte2] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NettoSummenspalte3] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NettoSummenspalte4] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NettoSummenspalte5] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NettoSummenspalte6] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NettoSummenspalte7] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NettoSummenspalte8] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NettoSummenspalte9] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NettoSummenspalte10] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NettoOhneSummenSpalte] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [MwStSummenspalte1] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [MwStSummenspalte2] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [MwStSummenspalte3] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [MwStBasisspalte1] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [MwStBasisspalte2] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [MwStBasisspalte3] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [BasisspalteOhneMwSt] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[KdNr] [int] NULL,
    [KdNachname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [KdVorname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [KdTelefon] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [KdMobilTelefon] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [KdEmail] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Kennz] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [BerKennz] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [KM] [int] NULL,
    [Laufleistung] [int] NULL,
    [RabattStufe] [int] NULL,
    [Adresse_ID] [int] NULL,
    [CPrLieferschein] [int] NULL,
    [BincMwSt] [bit] NULL,
[LandWKuerzel] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [Bemerkung] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Verkaeufer_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Sachbearbeiter_ID] [int] NULL,
[PersIDFaktura] [int] NULL,
    [Monteur_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Team_ID] [int] NULL,
    [CPrRepAngebot] [int] NULL,
    [CPrRepAuftr] [int] NULL,
    [CPrWerkstattkarte] [int] NULL,
    [CPrRechnung] [int] NULL,
    [CPrRechnungFormularName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CPrRepRechnKopie] [int] NULL,
    [CPrPickerzettel] [int] NULL,
    [CPrVorabRechn] [int] NULL,
    [CPrAuftrBestaet] [int] NULL,
    [BOhneFzDaten] [bit] NULL,
    [BOhneNr] [bit] NULL,
    [PrOhneEinzelpreis] [bit] NULL,
    [FHFzNW] [bit] NULL,
    [FHDifferenzbesteuert] [bit] NULL,
    [StornoZuAuftrNr] [int] NULL,
    [Storno_Datum] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [Buchungsdatum] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [VakBuchungsModus] [int] NULL,
    [DiffNettoKompZuSumme] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Vorgangsart_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Beschreibung] [ntext] NULL,
    [IsErreichbarTel1perSMS] [bit] NULL,
    [IsErreichbarTel1perTel] [bit] NULL,
    [IsErreichbarMobilperSMS] [bit] NULL,
    [IsErreichbarMobilperTel] [bit] NULL,
    [IsErreichbarEmail] [bit] NULL,
    [StundenGeschaetzt] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [WKZ_Zweitwaehrung] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [Kurs_Zweitwaehrung] [decimal](18, 7) NULL,
    [EndbetragInZweitwaehrung] [bit] NULL,
    [Kulanzursprung] [int] NULL,
    [IsKulanzgesplittet] [bit] NULL,
    [SplitUrsprung] [int] NULL,
    [IsGesplittet] [bit] NULL,
    [FlottenReparaturkostenId] [int] NULL,
    [NovaSatz] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NovaGesamt] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NovaBasis] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [NovaBonusMalus] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [FilialNr] [int] NULL,
    [Angebotverfall] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [IvecoSonderverkauf] [bit] NULL,
    [LetzteAenderung] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [IsAnzahlung] [bit] NULL,
    [AnzahlungSumme] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [SADESperre] [int] NULL,
    [SADEVersendet] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [MP2Angebotsnummer] [int] NULL,
    [SchadenNummer] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ReferenzAudaNet] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [LetzterBearbeiter] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Rechnername] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ReferenzAudaNetCaseId] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
[AuftragsanlageOrder] [bit] NULL,
    [RabattDrucken] [bit] NULL,
    [AuftragStatus1_ID] [int] NULL,
    [AuftragStatus2_ID] [int] NULL,
    [AuftragStatus3_ID] [int] NULL,
    [AuftragStatus4_ID] [int] NULL,
    [TeileZurueckBeiGutschrift] [bit] NULL,
    [StornoGrund_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Anleger_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Betriebsstunden] [int] NULL,
    [SperreSADE] [bit] NULL,
    [FiOnlineContractId] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [DWNichtMehrFragen] [bit] NULL,
    [BestellZaehler] [int] NULL,
    [NovaOhneAufschlag] [bit] NULL,
    [DefaultLager_ID] [int] NULL,
    [RechnungBezahltKennzeichnen] [bit] NULL,
    [AnVWBackboneAsNewReported] [bit] NULL,
    [VWBackboneRequestID] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [VWBackboneConversationID] [nvarchar](70) NULL,
    [VWBackboneStatusID] [int] NULL,
    [VWBackboneSaga2ClaimNr] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [VWBackboneSaga2GarantieAntragNr] [int] NULL,
    [VWBackboneSaga2MaxClaims] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AuftrKopf] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The strange thing is, that the conversions work on my computer with german-swiss settings, but not on the client-computer, which has a french setup.

Comment: Can you script the table "as create", and post the column definition for RechDatum?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem with the input of Laszlo Tenki.
I read the SET DATEFORMAT-article of the Microsoft Help again:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

It seems that there are some character string formats, that are independent of SET DATEFORMAT.
From the Microsoft-Article:
***Some character strings formats, for example ISO 8601, are interpreted independently of the DATEFORMAT setting. For more information about how to use DATEFORMAT with different formats see the "String Literal Date and Time Formats" section in Using Date and Time Data.***

The solution answer can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx

I could solve the problem with

```
SET LANGUAGE
```

Set language sets the SQL-Server-Settings for the Current Session.
The interpretation of String representations by the SQL-Server is dependent on SET DATEFORMAT and SET LANGUAGE.
The format I chose ISO 8601 is 'SET DATETIME'-independent, thats why that didn't work.
Check the info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx

However: Microsoft recommends the usage of ISO 8601, because it is multilanguage-compatible. That raises the question, why I needed to change the LANGUAGE at all.

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand why this affects a date string purely made of digits. But I'm glad you could solve it!

Comment: Interesting to note that YYYYMMDD is independent of formatting settings.  Very interesting find.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
DECLARE @datevar varchar(8) 
SET @datevar = '20111019'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@datevar,114) AS RechDatum
```

And this:

```
SELECT '20111019' AS RechDatum INTO #tmp
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,Rechdatum,114) AS RechDate from #tmp
```

works fine too. Are you sure you table column has the right type/format?

Comment: I think that the column is ok. The problem with the CONVERT-function is, that the third parameter is ignored, when converting from string to datetime. It just works from datetime to string, although it doesn't throw a syntax-error. That is written in the microsoft documentation.

Comment: Yes, i did? Can't find a column named "RechDatum"?!

Comment: Sorry Mithrandir, I hope you didn't lose the interest over that. I posted the wrong table.

Comment: So the problem is on system with a french locale, is it? On your swiss-german machine it's fine? I'm using a german SQL Server as well ...

Comment: exec sp_helplanguage 'German' and exec sp_helplanguage 'French' say, that both have standard DATEFORMAT of dmy, this should not be a problem.

Comment: I agree. I'm really out of ideas in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

SQL server has its own date formatting mechanism that is independent from the regional settings of the computer.

I would say that it is probably different on your developer machine and the production server. It looks that you can process dates in either format, your only problem is that it changes and you don't know for sure what to prepare for.

For SET DATEFORMAT, See the details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer Laszlo. But I couldn't solve the problem with SET DATEFORMAT. I used SET DATEFORMAT ymd; with no influence on the convert(datetime,[value])- function.